# What does JKR mean by Lily's protection adding some goodness to Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

Just read this on JKR's old [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20081231104945/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=122):

> Having taken Harry’s blood into himself, Voldemort is keeping alive Lily’s protective power over Harry. So Voldemort himself acts almost like a Horcrux for Harry – except that the power of Lily’s sacrifice is a positive force that not only continues to tether Harry to life, but gives Voldemort himself one last chance (Dumbledore refers to this last hope in chapter 35). **Voldemort has unwittingly put a few drops of goodness back inside himself**; if he had repented, he could have been healed more deeply than anyone would have supposed. But, of course, he refused to feel remorse."

What could the sentence: "Voldemort has unwittingly put a few drops of goodness back inside himself" mean?

Comment: I’m confused as to why a simple straightforward reading of the words is giving you difficulty?

Comment: I assume that it means that Voldermort unintentionally put a bit of Lily's love in himself by taking Harry's blood. Voldermort was never loved, and he could not love - hence why a few drops of blood  made a huge change.